# Необходимо диффузивно перемешать два массива

Tags: c#, массивы, разработка-игр

В общем задача такая: есть некий лист в котором хранятся куски генерированной карты, необходимо сделать плавный переход между такими лоскутами, взаимозаменяя элементы массивов друг у друга с плавным уменьшением.

Накатал небольшой пример:

```
class Program
{
    private static char[,] SimpleGenrator(char seed)
    {
        var result = new char[5,5];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                result[i, j] = seed;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void PrintMap(IEnumerable<char[,]> map)
    {
        foreach (var chunk in map)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(chunk[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Map = new List<char[,]>();
        Map.Add(SimpleGenrator('#'));
        Map.Add(SimpleGenrator('.'));

        //Магия диффузии

        PrintMap(Map);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы получить что то типа такого:

```
#####
####.
##.##
.###.
...#.
###.#
#...#
..#..
....#
.....
```

Comment: По какому принципу этот результат получился?

Comment: Ну конкретно этот получился потому что я ручную переставил местами различные элементы массивов между собой и чем ближе к линии пересечения, тем чаще менял. А в идеале хотелось бы чтобы они случайным образом диффузионно перемешивались, как бы проникая друг в друга

Comment: Как здесь например: http://prntscr.com/ic89wv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
static Random random = new Random();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int count = 5;
    char[,] map =
    {
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
        { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' }
    };

    int curIngress = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        curIngress += random.Next(0, 2);
        foreach (var j in Shuffle(count).Take(curIngress))
            map[i, j] = '.';
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++)
            Console.Write(map[i, j]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static IEnumerable<int> Shuffle(int count)
    => Enumerable.Range(0, count).OrderBy(x => random.Next());
```

У нас есть текущая "степень проникновения" `curIngress` и на каждом шаге мы ее увеличиваем на случайное число 0 или 1.

Но это самый простейший алгоритм, нужно доработать логику увеличения `curIngress`, например, более плавное проникновение получается при использовании  формулы такого плана:

```
curIngress += random.Next(0, 3) > curIngress - i ? 1 : 0;
```